# Merge cells in a specific column using pandas

Tags: merge

I want to merge blank cells in first column of a dataframe with the value at the top, and keep on repeating the process until the last row in the table. Also, would want to make changes just for this specific column, and want to keep the data in other columns as it is.

I tried groupby, merge etc. but couldn't find the correct solution.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.